# Kill Sessions in Tomcat via CURL

Tags: tomcat, curl

Edit: i now tried another method of sending my request (with the same result), by calling

```
curl "http://myUser:myPass@server:8080/manager/html/expire?path=/MyWebApp&idle=0"
```

even when i just put http://server:8080/manager/html/expire?path=/myWebApp in my browsers adress bar, there is no credential prompt but simply a 403 Access Denied Page (i run Tomcat 8.0)

---

As the title says : i try to kill all active sessions in an application in Tomcat and tried to do this with curl
my request looks like this (i am in no way sure if its correct):

```
curl --anyauth -u myUser:myPass --data "idle=0" -d path=/MyWebApp http://server:8080/manager/html/expire
```

All i get is an 403 Access Denied page.
The user is defined for the roles manager-gui, manager-jmx and manager-script.
What is the correct way to accomplish this? Is there a configuration i am missing, or is my request incorrect?

Comment: Do you have properly setup tomcat security? What happens if you open the manager app in your browser?

Comment: i can open the manager app in my browser With following user : <user username="user" password="pass" roles="manager-gui,manager-status"/>

Comment: i also removed the valve entry in my context.xml.the url i send is described in the section Expire Sessions in https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html, but i am not sure if there is something missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to define a User with the roles manager-jmx and manager-script, and i had to alter the url to (change the html part to text):

```
curl "http://user:pass@server:8080/manager/text/expire?path=/myWebApp&idle=0"
```